# How to access objects in lists? How to create many sequentially named objects at once?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want a long list of checkbuttons and entries. I create them using a `for` loop, however that won't allow me to assign unique names to the objects (e.g. textbox1, textbox2, etc), because you can't do `"foo" + char(i) = whatever`. So I created two lists, one for the checkbuttons and one for the entries. But how yould you access the objects in the list?

```
slot1list_check = []
slot1list_text = []

for x in range (1,21):
    label = "S1Ch. " + str(x)
    chk = Checkbutton(app, text=label).grid(row=(x+1), column=0)
    txt = Entry(app, text=label).grid(row=(x+1), column=1)
    slot1list_check.append(chk)
    slot1list_text.append(txt)
    slot1list_text[x-1].insert(0,"whatever in this field")
```

I get the following error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert', referring to the last line in the code above.

How would I go about accessing the objects in the list? Is there a smarter/better way to create a large number of objects and assign them sequential names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.grid()` method returns `None` as it alters the widget in-place. It does not return the `CheckButton()` or `Entry()` element.

Call `.grid()` *separately* instead:

```
slot1list_check = []
slot1list_text = []

for x in range (1,21):
    label = "S1Ch. " + str(x)
    chk = Checkbutton(app, text=label)
    chk.grid(row=(x+1), column=0)
    txt = Entry(app, text=label)
    txt.grid(row=(x+1), column=1)
    slot1list_check.append(chk)
    slot1list_text.append(txt)
    slot1list_text[x-1].insert(0,"whatever in this field")
```

Note that I moved the `.grid()` calls to a new line, using the `chk` and `txt` references.

You can reference the last element in a list with `-1` as negative indices count from the end of the list backwards. In this case you already have the `txt` reference to the same object, so you could use that directly.

Personally, I'd just use `range(20)` and use `+ 1` where needed:

```
slot1list_check = []
slot1list_text = []

for x in range(20):
    label = "S1Ch. {}".format(x + 1)

    chk = Checkbutton(app, text=label)
    chk.grid(row=x + 2, column=0)
    slot1list_check.append(chk)

    txt = Entry(app, text=label)
    txt.grid(row=x + 2, column=1)
    txt.insert(0,"whatever in this field")
    slot1list_text.append(txt)
```